# Changing CGRect then clicking text field returns to original position

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, uiviewanimation

So I have a problem and I'm not entirely sure what's going on. I am writing a little application for iOS in Swift.

On a button click I am running an animation to move an element:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
    self.blurView.alpha = 1.0;
    self.logoImage.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 65, width: 100, height: 101);
})

loginFormView.hidden = false;
```

This runs fine and animation but then when I click on the text field it jumps the animated logo to its original position and size.

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout for your app?

Comment: Yeah i am on the logoImage.

Comment: So you found your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh i found out what i was doing wrong i was animating an image that had a constraint on it so i just needed to animate the Y constraint.

self.view.layoutIfNeeded();

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

        self.blurView.alpha = 1.0;
        self.Yconst.constant = 200;

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
    })
```